# Replacing a pattern in a text file with a random value

Tags: regex, bash, text, sed, awk

I have a text file with this pattern:

```
\t (hello world)
```

I need to replace the text in parenthesis with a unique value (e.g. ob1, obj2, etc), such that

```
\t (obj)
\t (obj)
\t (obj)
```

becomes...

```
\t (obj1)
\t (obj2)
\t (obj3)
```

Or anything else that is unique. A solution that uses any tool that works in cygwin will work. My attempt using bash and sed to do this failed:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=1
for fl in myfile; do
    cp $fl $fl.old
    sed 's/\\t \(.*\)/\\t \("${x}"\)/g' $fl.old > $fl.new
    x=$((x+1))
    echo $x
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know how to do this is with a perl in-place edit:

E.g. myfile.txt contains:

```
\t (obj)
\t (obj)
\t (obj)
```

Run the in-place edit:

```
perl -i.bak -ne '$a=int(rand()*2000); s/\((.*?)\)/{$1$a}/g; print' myfile.txt
```

myfile.txt now contains:

```
\t (obj1869)
\t (obj665)
\t (obj1459)
```

Obviously adjust `2000` to your requirements.

**EDIT**: If you wish to use incrementing identifiers use:

```
perl -i.bak -ne '$a++; s/\((.*?)\)/{$1$a}/g; print' myfile.txt
```

Comment: +1 my thought was to use perl too. One of the requirements is uniqueness, so need to track the identifiers used. Simpler to just use an incrementing counter.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be changing the contents of the file (no errors). I don't know perl and even I can follow what's going on here. I'm using Cygwin. Are there any characters in that statement that need to escape maybe?

Comment: @Scribblemacher I've just noticed that your two input data examples are different, one uses `{` and one uses `(` could that be the problem, I'm assuming `{`.

Comment: You may want `perl -i.bak -ne '$a++; s/\((.*?)\)/{$1$a}/g; print' myfile.txt` which looks for tokens enclosed in `(` and `)`.

Comment: That was exactly it. I completely overlooked the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=[(])[^)]*/"obj" . ++$count/eg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex...It uses sed's "extended" regular expressions.

```
sed -r -e "s/\t \((.*)\)/\t \1${x}/g"
```

However, I'm not sure if your question wants `obj` to go to `obj1`, `obj2`, ... in the same file, or if each file gets it's own unique `obj1`, `obj2` ...

**EDIT** Apparently you need to read the file line by line...something like this might work.

```
x=1
while read line; do echo ${line} |  sed -r -e "s/\t \((.*)\)/\t \1${x}/g"; let "x=x+1"; done < myfile.txt > myfile.new.txt
```

of course, it is probably simpler to use `perl` as the others have done